# Convergence of $\int_0^n f(x)\, dx - [\frac{1}{2} f(0) + f(1) +\dots + f(n-1) + \frac{1}{2} f(n)]$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods

If $f(x)$ is increasing, strictly concave, and twice continuously differentiable for $x > 0$, does the difference
$$
d_n = \int_0^n f(x)\, dx - [\tfrac{1}{2} f(0) + f(1) + f(2) +\dots + f(n-1) + \tfrac{1}{2} f(n)]
$$
converge to a finite positive limit when $n\to +\infty$?

The error form provided by the trapezoidal rule is not helpful since it just asserts that $d_n = -n f''(\xi_n)/12\geqslant 0$, for some $0 < \xi_n < n$, or that
$$
d_n\leqslant -\tfrac{1}{12}[f''(\xi_1) + f''(\xi_2) +\dots + f''(\xi_n)]
$$
with  $k-1 < \xi_k < k$. Since $f(x)$ is increasing and concave, then $f''(x)$ is negative, bounded, and increasing for $x > 0$, but then again, how to assure the converge of $\sum_{k=1}^n f''(\xi_n)$ when $n\to +\infty$?

Comment: You know more, you know that $f'(x)\ge0$ is monotonically falling, which forces $f''(x)\to0$ for $x\to\infty$. Somewhere this should be sufficient to show that the sequence $d_n$ is Cauchy or directly that it converges...

Comment: Increasing and concave does not imply differentiable.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Right, but in such a case $f(x)$ is differentiable almost everywhere; anyway, I was clearly assuming all along that $f(x)$ was $\mathcal{C^2}$.

Comment: But it's not in the statement of the question. Anyway, the answers do not require this assumption.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut Not explicitly, but it is implicitly stated since I did talk about the boundedness of $f′′(x)$, I did apply the mean value theorem to $f'(x)$ and therefore to its derivative $f′′(x)$, and mainly I was estimating the error giving by the trapezoid rule which assumes $f′′(x)$ to be continuous. Yet still not enough material to deduce the assumptions?

Comment: More like the smoothness you need strict concavity, or else the limit may not be positive as the example $f(x)=x$ shows. Or do you live in a region where $0$ is both positive and negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, the answer has to lie in the conflict field of "increasing" and "concave". Let's try a solution without referring to derivatives.

**Concave:** implies that for $x\in[a,b]$ one has that the function graph is above the secant,
$$
f(x)\ge \frac{(x-a)f(b) + (b-x)f(a)}{b-a}
\implies \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\, dx\ge \frac12 (f(n) + f(n+1)).
$$

Switching the points around, that is, exchanging $x$ and $b$ and again isolating $f(x)$ gives for $a < b < x$
$$
(x-a)f(b)\ge (b-a)f(x) + (x-b)f(a)\\
f(x)\le \frac{(x-a)f(b) + (b-x)f(a)}{b-a},
$$
which implies
\begin{align}
\int_{n+1}^{n+2} f(x)\, dx
&\le \int_{n+1}^{n+2}[(x-n)f(n+1) + (n+1-x)f(n)]\, dx\\
&=\frac12(3f(n+1)-f(n)),
\end{align}
so that
$$
0\le \int_n^{n+1} f(x)\, dx - \frac1 2(f(n)+f(n+1))\le \frac12 [2f(n)-f(n+1)-f(n-1)].
$$

Summing up from $m$ till $n$ we get
\begin{align}
0 &\le d_n-d_m\\
&= \int_m^n f(x)\, dx -\Bigl(\frac12 f(m)+ f(m+1) +\dots + f(n-1) +\frac12 f(n)\Bigr)\\
&\le \frac12 (f(m)-f(m-1)) -\frac12 (f(n) - f(n-1)). \tag{*}
\end{align}

---

From concavity we saw that $2f(n) - f(n+1) - f(n-1)\ge 0$. It immediately follows that the sequence $v_n = f(n+1) - f(n)$ is monotonically falling. Because $f$ is increasing, this sequence stays non-negative, so it has a non-negative limit $v$. This means that the sequence $v_n$ is a Cauchy sequence, and (*) then implies that also the sequence of the $d_n$ is Cauchy. Thus it has a limit, which can not be negative.

Comment: Very a crafty chain of estimations! How did you come up with it? The geometrical idea hidden behind the inequalities is so simple and yet not obvious at first sight: While the function is greater than any of the secants on their corresponding intervals, the same function is less than the previous secant!

Comment: Yes, the geometric shape of the secant. And the first idea was as I commented via the derivatives, if one could ignore the third derivative you get that the error over an interval is $\frac1{12}(f'(n)-f'(n+1))$ which gives a telescoping sum for the total error. // Using the secants from both neighboring intervals one can make an even tighter upper bound, somewhat similar to the spline construction via convex combinations. But this already was sufficient.

Answer (score 3):

Consider
$$
f(x)=-\frac{1}{(x+1)(x+2)}.
$$
Clearly $f$ is increasing and concave in $[0,\infty)$.

Then
$$
\frac{1}{2}f(0)+f(1)+\cdots+f(n-1)+\frac{1}{2}f(n)=\cdots=-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{1}{2(n+1)(n+2)}\\=-\frac{3}{4}+\frac{1}{n}+{\mathcal O}(n^{-2})
$$
while
$$
\int_0^n f(x)\,dx=\int_0^n \frac{dx}{x+2}-\int_0^n\frac{dx}{x+1}=\log(n+2)-\log 2-\log(n+1)\\=-\log 2-\log\Big(1+\frac{1}{n+1}\Big)\\=-\log 2-\frac{1}{n}+{\mathcal O}(n^{-2})
$$
Thus
$$
d_n\to -\frac{1}{2}+\log 2>0.
$$

Comment: Your $f(x)$ is clearly not increasing.

Comment: @Fitzcarraldo Correct. I changed my answer.

Comment: $$\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(\frac1{k+2}-\frac1{k+1}\right)=\frac1{n+1}-\frac12$$ so that $$\frac12f(0)+f(1)+...+f(n-1)+\frac12f(n)=-\frac14-\frac12+\frac1{n+1}-\frac1{2(n+1)(n+2)}$$ Thus the limit is $-\frac34$, not $-\frac12$. Because of the concavity it is clear that the limit of the original expression, if it exists, has to be non-negative. So the only question in this is if the limit exists.

Comment: Of course, taking it literally has that $f(x)=x$ is concave and increasing and has the difference always zero, never positive, so the limit will not be positive.

Comment: The last should be $d_n\to\frac34-\ln2=0.056852...>0$. Where remains the justification for the emphatic "NO"?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis So, at the end of the day, what's the point of this non-counterexample?